# How can I instantiate a qiskit BackendConfiguration object from a dictionary?

Tags: qiskit

I know that `BackendConfiguration` has the [method](https://qiskit-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/qiskit.providers.models.BackendConfiguration.html) `from_dict(dict)` but I don't know how to use it. Can someone give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest the `BackendConfiguration` class is not the most ergonomic to use, and it really is just a mapping of the IBM Quantum API response to a Python object (it was explicitly this in the early releases of Qiskit, but was made independent a long time ago) when querying for a backend's configuration. This is why the class isn't used in `BackendV2` having been replaced by backend attributes and the `Target` class. This is more vendor agnostic and easier to work with. You can see details of this here:
https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/providers.html#backendv1-backendv2 for details of the difference.

As for how to use the `BackendConfiguration.from_dict()` constructor method, it's basically designed to take in the JSON parsed output from the IBM quantum api response payload. However, the best example of doing it manually is honestly the old version of the aqt provider (since on main it's already moved to `BackendV2` to avoid this). See:

https://github.com/Qiskit-Partners/qiskit-aqt-provider/blob/0.4.2/qiskit_aqt_provider/aqt_backend.py#L35-L57

which on line 59 is passed to `BackendConfiguration.from_dict()`. That shows you how to create a minimal `BackendConfiguration` object from an input dictionary.